# Apache: X-Request-ID like in Heroku

Tags: apache-2.4, uniqueidentifier

I like `X-Request-ID`:

> The Heroku router generates a unique request ID for every incoming HTTP request that it receives. This unique ID is then passed to your application as an HTTP header called X-Request-ID.

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id

How can I configure Apache to provide `X-Request-ID` which is different, even if a multi-threaded MPM gets used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Load the [unique_id_module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_unique_id.html). This provides the UNIQUE_ID environment variable which serves this purpose.

   ```
   LoadModule mod_unique_id.c
   ```
2. Copy the UNIQUE_ID into the `X-Request-ID` header in the appropriate virtual host using the [`RequestHeader`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive.

   ```
   RequestHeader setifempty X-Request-ID %{UNIQUE_ID}e
   ProxyPass ...
   ProxyPassReverse ...
   ```

Optionally, you can also put `%{UNIQUE_ID}e` into a [custom log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) so that you can log it from Apache (possibly in addition to within your application).

Comment: Since "X-Request-ID" seems the more common name, I will add this to the log format, and not "UNIQUE_ID". Do you agree?

Comment: @guettli Do you want the actual unique ID logged, or the literal string "X-Request-ID"?

Comment: I want the contents of the variable: the unique id, not the literal string. I would like to have a set up which is like on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id

Comment: @guettli Then you should do what I advised.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to escape the value of %{UNIQUE_ID}e for the header.
This article describes it as the first example:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/env.html#examples

```
#
# The following works around a client sending a broken Accept_Encoding
# header.
#
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Accept.Encoding$ ^(.*)$ fix_accept_encoding=$1
RequestHeader set Accept-Encoding %{fix_accept_encoding}e env=fix_accept_encoding
```